# Manipular um iframe através de outro iframe

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Olá, eu estou com uma dúvida e gostaria de pedir a ajuda de vocês. Bom, eu vou tentar explicar mais ou menos o problema (os nomes que eu vou citar é só para exemplo).
 
Imagina que eu tenho um arquivo chamado "principal.php", daí dentro deste arquivo tem dois Iframes:

O primeiro iframe contém o arquivo "iframe1.php"

O segundo iframe contém o arquivo "iframe2.php".

Agora vamos imaginar que eu estou com o primeiro iframe aberto em formato de modal(ou fancyBox), e eu quero que através deste primeiro iframe, eu consiga recarregar o outro iframe que também está referenciado no arquivo "principal.php".

Eu tinha tentado dessa forma, mas infelizmente não funcionou:

```js
window.parent.$('#iframe-sistema').location.reload(true);
```

Só para esclarecer. O "iframe1.php" seria um iframe de listagem de dados que vem do banco de dados, que ao clicar em excluir, ele vai abrir o "iframe2.php" em formato de modal (ou fancyBox,popup,etc) que vai perguntar se eu desejo realmente excluir aquele registro.
 Após confirmar a exclusão, este mesmo iframe (o "iframe2.php") vai exibir uma mensagem se ocorreu tudo certo e depois que apertar o botão "ok", ele vai se auto fechar e recarregar o "iframe1.php" para mostrar os registros que restaram após a exclusão de um registro.
Eu sei que para alguns isso pode parecer um uso excessivo de iframe, mas a questão é que isso é um sistema que vai ser bem modular, onde o uso de código tem que ser reaproveitável para que não haja repetição de código e consequentemente acabar gerando um sistema pesado e de difícil manutenção. Se alguém também souber uma solução alternativa para o uso de iframes, eu agradeço. =D Obs: (Eu utilizo a função load() do Jquery em algumas partes deste sistema, mas não sei se nessa situação pode dar certo).

Comment: Os dois iFrames estão no mesmo domínio? porque não fazes isso sem iFrame?

Comment: Sim. Inclusive as referências dos dois iframes estão no mesmo arquivo. Eu não gosto muito de usar iframes, mas neste caso eu ainda não encontrei uma alternativa o uso de iframes.

Comment: Se descreveres o que queres fazer nós percebemos melhor o problema e pode ser que aprendas uma maneira melhor de fazer isso...

Comment: Ok. Vou tentar melhorar a descrição do problema.

Comment: Lucas: esquece a ideia de iFrame! Faz isso com o `.load()`. Uma div que exibe o que queres com conteúdo dinamico e o dialog para interagir (pedir confirmações) ao usuário. Se colocares mais código que tens na página posso dar uma sugestão durante o fds. Se ninguem ajudar antes.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu vou tentar da forma como você disse. Qualquer coisa eu volto aqui para falar o resultado.

Comment: @LucasCavalcanti, já que você mesmo resolveu seu problema, poderia, talvez remover a solução da pergunta e criar um resposta para sua própria pergunta, explicando a sua solução. Ficaria mais fácil de identificar a solução ao seu problema (eu li a pergunta toda para depois descobrir que estava resolvido, =D), e ainda é possível receber votos em sua resposta.

Comment: Obrigado. Vou fazer isso ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solução:**
Eu tentei seguir a ideia do Sergio de usar o "load()", porém no meu caso isso é meio complicado de utilizar. Eu particularmente prefiro o load, pois o código pode carregar mais rápido, porém eu teria que misturar muitos arquivos JS, CSS no mesmo arquivo, então eu optei por utilizar o iframe mesmo. Dessa forma, eu consegui atualizar um iframe através de outro iframe:

```js
window.parent.document.getElementById(iframe).contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```