# Recarregar iframe dentro de uma modal

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Vejam meu cenário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na página pai eu tenho 3 divs. modalFilha2, modalFilha2, modalFilha3 na qual eu vou chamando de acordo com a página que eu esteja. Quando estou na pai os links chamam a filha1 e adicionam um iframe com a pagina que eu quero, e assim sucessivamente.

O que eu preciso é, da pagina filha2 recarregar a filha1.
Da filha3 recarregar a filha2.

Tentei `window.parent.location.reload();` chamar isso na filha2 para recarregar a filha1, mas ele sempre carregar a pai.

Comment: Qual a necessidade de abrir tantas janelas em cadeia assim?

Comment: Navegação entre telas sem uso de histórico, mantendo navegação como se fosse desktop!

Comment: window.parent.document.getElementById(iframe).contentDocument.location.reload(true);  veja em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54295/manipular-um-iframe-atrav%C3%A9s-de-outro-iframe

Answer (score -2):

Resolvi com a ideia do @Leo Craccilolo
usando o que está descrito aqui -> [Manipular um iframe através de outro iframe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54295/manipular-um-iframe-atrav%C3%A9s-de-outro-iframe)

Comment: Não indique apenas que resolveu. Coloque aqui o código que utilizou para resolver para que futuras pessoas com o mesmo problema possam beneficiar da sua pergunta.